Segmentation fault in the code to reverse an array
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
int n,i,j;
int arr[n];
cin>>n;
for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    cin >> arr[j];
}
for (i = n+1; i >=0; i--) {
    cout << arr[i] << " ";
}
}

for most of the test cases it is showing segmentation fault for the given code. How to resolve it?
The code doesn't work for the all the test cases.

What is the value of n when you create int arr[n];?

Side notes: (1) Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>? (2) What's the problem with "using namespace std;"?.

int arr[n] uses a non-standard C++ extension (in some compilers) called Variable Length Arrays, you should instead use std::vector<int> if you need a runtime sized array

@Yksisarvinen And what is the value of n+1 when you set i to n+1 then do arr[i].  It is harder to find a line of code that doesn't have a segfault in this code...

n is is uninitialized meaning int arr[n]; is undefined behavior.

Sorry for being frank, but each line of this code is terrible. You need to slow down and learn C++ basics: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Ho stop... you are NOT learning C++ (at least not the normal standard C++). Where are you trying to learn C++ from?

There is a difference between "print an array in reverse" and "reverse an array." It looks like you just need to print it in reverse?

Your code should actually look something like this :
//#include <bits/stdc++.h> <== NO not standard C++
//using namespace std; <== not recommended

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ranges>

int main()
{
    //int n,i,j; // C++ does not initialize your variables for you
    //int arr[n]; n is unitialized here bad things will happen. AND this is not valid C++

    std::size_t n; // sizes of data structures are not ints
    std::cin >> n;

    std::vector<int> values(n);

    // Don't use index based for loops if you do not explicitly need indices
    //for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    //cin >> arr[j];
    //}

    // use range based for loops if you can
    for(int& value : values)
    {
        std::cin >> value;
    }


    //for (i = n+1; i >=0; i--) {
      //  cout << arr[i] << " ";
    //}

    // and if you are only reading values use `const`
    // and in C++ you can use views to do a reverse loop
    for(const int value : values | std::views::reverse)
    {
        std::cout << value << "\n";
    }
}


I would argue that the range-based for loops should use auto. And if you're busting out C++20, I would further recommend std::format or jump to C++23 and std::println.

@sweenish fair points :)
